# There is no return statement

Tags: java, arrays, object, return, indexof

I wrote a method in order to print the details of the employees that exists in an array called myEmployees. The exercise says that I should return an integer, specifically the index of the object employee and I did as asked, but it says that there is no return statement.

```
private int findEmployeeByName(String empName) {
    for(Employee e: this.myEmployees) {
        if(e!=null && e.getEmpName().equals(empName))  {
            return e.getEmpName().indexOf(empName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not handling the case when `this.myEmployees` is empty.

Comment: In addition to what @Pshemo wrote: Do you really want to return the index of a substring in employee's name? This is what indexOf() does. It is asked to return the index within the employee list.

Comment: @yacc is right. You need the index inside your list. In that case a good old for-Loop (instead of foreach) is better. `for(int i=0; i<this.myEmployees.size();i++)`. Then you just return the value of `i` inside your if.

Comment: not only not handling that `this.myEmployees` may be empty, but also ignoring the possibility that no name matches `empName` - in that case the `for` will also be terminated without executing `return` but the method *must* return an `int` (or throw an `Exception`)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging

Comment: Okay, I see, so I’m going to correct them and upload a better version of this method. Thank a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

*Think like this,*

In your method if the there is no chance to satisfy **`if (condition)`** at all, then what will the method return?

*In your case,*

If you never find an employee with the given name, how do you want to handle the return statement, it's up to you.

You can return -1 or any `integer` *(Remember, you should not use the value that is an index)*.

You can handle it from where you are calling the method.

```
int index = findEmployeeByName("Barbara Riga");

if (index == -1) {
  System.out.println("Employee not found!");
} else {
  System.out.println("Index of the employee: " + index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
private int findEmployeeByName(String empName) {
   for(Employee e: this.myEmployees) {
      if(e!=null && e.getEmpName().equals(empName))  {
          return e.getEmpName().indexOf(empName);
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement after the for-Loop, in case `this.myEmployees` is empty, even if you surely know, that this never happens.

So just return -1

Another place where your code wouldn't return anything is, when an employee name is not inside the list

Comment: If you know this never happens it would be better to throw a `RuntimeException` imho.

Comment: yes, you are right, but for a beginner it maybe be better to start with an additional return.

Comment: I think the other reason is more likely, that the employee is not inside the list and then a runtime exception seems a little bit too much because it is a normal and not an  errornous case.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what to do and it was simpler than I thought!

```
/*
     * This method is used to find an existing project
     * from myProjects array, using the project's name
     * (projName) and should return its index, else it 
     * return -1.
     * Parameter:
     *  String projName --> project's name.
     */
public int findProjectByName(String projName) {
     
    for(int i=0; i<numOfProjects; i++)
        if((myProjects[i].getProjectName()).equals(projName))
            return i;
    System.out.println("No project found.");
    return -1;
}
```